# Algorithm - Find maximum sum of two numbers in unsorted array that have a minimum distance

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to find an algorithm that finds the maximum sum of two numbers that have a minimum distance **D** between them.

For example, lets say we have this array of 8 numbers and the minimum distance for a sum is **2**:

```
9 4 6 2 8 7 5 6

9 can be paired with  2, 8, 7, 5, 6
4 can be paired with  8, 7, 5, 6
6 can be paired with  7, 5, 6
2 can be paired with  9 (from the left side), 5, 6
8 can be paired with  9, 4 and 6
etc..
```

From this array it is obvious that the maximum possible sum is 9+8 = 17

Does anyone know of an efficient algorithm to do this, or has any idea?

I have tried an algorithm which finds the max number, compares it with every possible else, and then checks every value that does not have a minimum distance from it with every possible else...but this is very slow when the array consists of many numbers and the especially when the minimum distance is large.

Note: All numbers are **positive**

Thanks.

Comment: Your algorithm looks OK... is O(n*D) really too slow to you? Perhaps you have a bad implementation?

Comment: I tried it with 2 million numbers and a distance of 800.000, and well it didn't finish in the minute that I waited.

Comment: So D is huge. Try to apply some trivial optimizations.

Comment: You can match a number x with numbers in (-inf, x - D] and [x + D, inf). In the latter interval, the maximum of the array is certainly optimal. In the former, the predecessor of x - D is the optimum. You can find it via binary search after sorting the array. Total runtime will be O(n log n)

Comment: The only problem is that the array must not be sorted.

Comment: Well then, copy the array and sort the copy. I'm pretty sure you can't do well with o(n) extra space here (note little-o, not big-O)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each position in the array, find and store the maximum of the elements up to that position. This can be done in O(n) for all positions by updating the maximum in each step.

By scanning right-to-left in the same manner, find and store for each position the maximum of all elements from that position to the end.

Now for each element, `array[pos] + max(max_up_to[pos-D], max_from[pos+D])` will give you the highest sum that can be generated with that element. So another O(n) pass gives you the maximum over all elements.

Total: O(n) time, O(n) space.

In fact, you don't even need the additional space: The `max_from` array isn't needed because it's enough to evaluate `array[pos] + max_up_to[pos-D]` (since each sum would otherwise be generated twice). And the `max_up_to` values can be generated on-the-fly as you're iterating over the array.

Comment: When you say "from that position to the end", end is left, right?

Comment: @urel: In that pass you go from right-to-left, so, yes, left is right :)

Comment: Sounds good to me! I'll try it out, probably tomorrow, and I'll let you know.

Comment: @urel "the end" means the rightmost element. But as I say at the end of the answer, you don't actually need to calculate that since it's enough to add each element with the max element to its left (at distance>D).